# How to define prompt weights to huggingface's diffusers.StableDiffusionInpaintPipeline?

Tags: python, huggingface, stable-diffusion

I am tweaking a python script using diffusers inpainting pipeline for a custom video generation idea.

**I would like to gradually shift the weights of certain words in the prompt.**

As I understand the argument [prompt_embeds](https://huggingface.co/docs/diffusers/api/pipelines/stable_diffusion/inpaint#diffusers.StableDiffusionInpaintPipeline.__call__.prompt_embeds) is exactly what i need.

I could not figure out how to define this argument. Can someone pls provide an example?

I know there are frameworks out there where you can just add weights to certain words with the following syntax:

"This is a SD prompt with plus 50% weight added to the last (word:1.5)"

This would be a great solution as well however this does not work with diffusers.StableDiffusionInpaintPipeline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example from the original repo of [Compel](https://github.com/damian0815/compel) library:

```
from diffusers import StableDiffusionPipeline
from compel import Compel

pipeline = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained("runwayml/stable-diffusion-v1-5")
compel = Compel(tokenizer=pipeline.tokenizer, text_encoder=pipeline.text_encoder)

# upweight "ball"
prompt = "a cat playing with a ball++ in the forest"
conditioning = compel.build_conditioning_tensor(prompt)
# or: conditioning = compel([prompt])

# generate image
images = pipeline(prompt_embeds=conditioning, num_inference_steps=20).images
images[0].save("image.jpg")
```

So, as you can see, you should add `++`, or `--`, or `-----` and so on.
For your case it would be like `"This is a SD prompt with plus 50% weight added to the last word+++++"`. Also you can up\downweight subprompt: `A rich and descriptive (a subprompt goes here)++++ prompt`.